# Windows command to display all attributes of a file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I see that windows displays the attributes on my file as ALO.
I need a Windows (not Powershell command) to list attributes on my file.

But when I use attrib command. It shows only set attribute as A
LO attributes are missed.

OS: Windows 7.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/attrib

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc246322.aspx

Comment: Do you need a DOS command or do you need a Windows command? The two are _very_ different, and I find it unlikely (although not impossible) that you need a DOS command in 2019.

Comment: Also, `L` and `O` are not valid file attributes in Windows 7; what do you think they mean?

Comment: I need a windows command.

Comment: @SomethingDark 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc246322.aspx has the extended attributes

Comment: I looked it up on Wikipedia since that link doesn't have the initials. You want files that have the `Archive`, `Reparse Point`, and `Offline` attributes set.

Comment: [`attrib`](http://ss64.com/nt/attrib.html) should be able to read `A`, `L`, `O` attributes. Alternatives are: [`for`](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)`%F in ("D:\path\to\file.ext") do echo`[`%~aF`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) (change `%`to `%%` in a batch file), [`wmic`](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html)`DataFile where "Name='D:\\path\\to\\file.ext'" get`, [`fsutil`](http://ss64.com/nt/fsutil.html)`usn readdata "D:\path\to\file.ext"` (requires administrative privileges)...

Comment: This is a better list https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/file-attribute-constants

Answer (score 1):

Roll your own

**ConsoleAttr.vb**

```
imports System.Runtime.InteropServices 
Public Module MyApplication  

Public Declare Unicode Function GetFileAttributesW Lib "Kernel32" (ByVal Path As String) As Integer
Public Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE = 32 
Public Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPRESSED = 2048 
Public Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVICE = 64 
Public Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY = 16 
Public Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ENCRYPTED = 16384 
Public Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN = 2 
Public Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_INTEGRITY_STREAM = 32768 
Public Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL = 128 
Public Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NOT_CONTENT_INDEXED = 8192 
Public Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NO_SCRUB_DATA = 131072 
Public Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_OFFLINE = 4096 
Public Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY = 1 
Public Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_RECALL_ON_DATA_ACCESS = 4194304 
Public Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_RECALL_ON_OPEN = 262144 
Public Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT = 1024 
Public Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SPARSE_FILE = 512 
Public Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM = 4 
Public Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY = 256 
Public Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_VIRTUAL = 65536 

Public Sub Main ()
    Dim Ret as Integer
    Dim OutPut As String
    Output = Command() & " "
    Ret = GetFileAttributesW(Command())
    If Ret = 0 Then 
        Console.writeline("Error " & err.lastdllerror)
    Else
        If (Ret And FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE) = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE Then Output = OutPut & "Archive "
        If (Ret And FILE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPRESSED) = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPRESSED Then Output = OutPut & "Compressed "
        If (Ret And FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVICE) = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVICE Then Output = OutPut & "Device "
        If (Ret And FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY Then Output = OutPut & "Directory "
        If (Ret And FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ENCRYPTED) = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ENCRYPTED Then Output = OutPut & "Encrypted "
        If (Ret And FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN) = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN Then Output = OutPut & "Hidden "
        If (Ret And FILE_ATTRIBUTE_INTEGRITY_STREAM) = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_INTEGRITY_STREAM Then Output = OutPut & "Integrity_Stream "
        If (Ret And FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL) = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL Then Output = OutPut & "Normal "
        If (Ret And FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NOT_CONTENT_INDEXED) = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NOT_CONTENT_INDEXED Then Output = OutPut & "Not_Content_Indexed "
        If (Ret And FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NO_SCRUB_DATA) = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NO_SCRUB_DATA Then Output = OutPut & "No_Scrub_Data "
        If (Ret And FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY) = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY Then Output = OutPut & "ReadOnly "
        If (Ret And FILE_ATTRIBUTE_RECALL_ON_DATA_ACCESS) = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_RECALL_ON_DATA_ACCESS Then Output = OutPut & "Recall_On_Data_Access "
        If (Ret And FILE_ATTRIBUTE_RECALL_ON_OPEN) = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_RECALL_ON_OPEN Then Output = OutPut & "Recall_On_Open "
        If (Ret And FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT) = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT Then Output = OutPut & "Reparse "
        If (Ret And FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SPARSE_FILE) = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SPARSE_FILE Then Output = OutPut & "Sparse "
        If (Ret And FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM) = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM Then Output = OutPut & "System "
        If (Ret And FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY) = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY Then Output = OutPut & "Temporary "
        If (Ret And FILE_ATTRIBUTE_VIRTUAL) = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_VIRTUAL Then Output = OutPut & "Virtual "
    End If
    Console.writeline(OutPut)
End Sub
End Module
```

To compile

**ConsoleAttr.bat**

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc "%~dp0\ConsoleAttr.vb" /out:"%~dp0\ConsoleAttr.exe" /target:exe
```

Some examples

```
C:\Windows\system32>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\ConsoleAttr.exe" \\?\c:\bootnxt
\\?\c:\bootnxt Archive Hidden System

C:\Windows\system32>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\ConsoleAttr.exe" \\?\c:\windows\winsxs
\\?\c:\windows\winsxs Directory

C:\Windows\system32>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\ConsoleAttr.exe" c:\windows\win.ini
c:\windows\win.ini Archive
```

To do multiple files put in a for loop.

```
For %A in ("c:\windows\*.exe") Do @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\ConsoleAttr.exe" %A

c:\windows\bfsvc.exe Archive
c:\windows\explorer.exe Archive
c:\windows\extrac32.exe Archive
c:\windows\HelpPane.exe Archive
c:\windows\hh.exe Archive
c:\windows\notepad.exe Archive
c:\windows\regedit.exe Archive
c:\windows\REGTLIB.EXE Archive
```

Or for Directories

```
For /d %A in ("c:\windows\system32\*") Do @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\ConsoleAttr.exe" %A
```